# How to determine which self-attributes are referenced in a method?

Tags: python

Given:

```
class A(object):
  def m(self):
    print self.x + self.y + self.z()
```

Is there a way to query:

```
self_attributes_referenced(A.m) #=> ['x', 'y']
```

without doing decompiling or parsing?

Is there a corresponding way to get self-methods invoked as well?

```
self_methods_referenced(A.m) #=> ['z']
```

Comment: The closest I've come to is using the ``dis`` module. However that would require some parsing of the output which I don't have time for :/

Comment: It's not clear exactly what you are trying to do. Are you trying to find a way to see if attributes have been set/used/viewed and the same for methods? Or something else?

Comment: This seems like an odd thing to want to do. For one thing, it's poking through an abstraction barrier you generally shouldn't poke. For another, it won't tell you as much as you might expect. Consider `def method(self): return self.__helper_that_does_all_the_work()`. Who knows what this does?

Answer (score 1):

Something like this should work:

```
import inspect


class Referee(object):
    def __getattribute__(self, name):
        attr = object.__getattribute__(self, name)
        if inspect.ismethod(attr):
            try:
                meths_referenced = object.__getattribute__(
                    self, 'meths_referenced')
            except AttributeError:
                meths_referenced = set()
                object.__setattr__(self, 'meths_referenced', meths_referenced)

            meths_referenced.add(name)
        else:
            try:
                attrs_referenced = object.__getattribute__(
                    self, 'attrs_referenced')
            except AttributeError:
                attrs_referenced = set()
                object.__setattr__(self, 'attrs_referenced', attrs_referenced)

            attrs_referenced.add(name)

        return attr


def attributes_referenced(obj):
    try:
        return object.__getattribute__(obj, 'attrs_referenced')
    except AttributeError:
        return set()


def methods_referenced(obj):
    try:
        return object.__getattribute__(obj, 'meths_referenced')
    except AttributeError:
        return set()


class A(Referee):
    def __init__(self):
        self.x = 1
        self.y = 2

    def z(self):
        return 3

    def m(self):
        print self.x + self.y + self.z()


a = A()
a.m()
print attributes_referenced(a)
print methods_referenced(a)
```

This prints:

```
6
set(['y', 'x'])
set(['z', 'm'])
```

Inherit from `Referee` whenever you want to provide this functionality. **Why** you need this functionality is beyond my comprehension. =)

Comment: This is quite possibly the most painful thing I have ever seen. Kudos to you for having the will power to even write it.

Answer (score 1):

In the question you exclude parsing as a solution, but were you aware of how bafflingly easy it is to parse and modify Python source with the [**ast** module](http://docs.python.org/dev/library/ast.html)?

First define a `NodeTransformer`:

```
import ast

class RecordReferencesTransformer(ast.NodeTransformer):
    def visit_FunctionDef(self, node):
        def is_attr_on_self(n):
            return type(n) is ast.Attribute and type(n.value) is ast.Name and n.value.id == 'self'

        targets = [ast.Attribute(value=ast.Name(id=node.name, ctx=ast.Load()), attr='self_attributes_referenced', ctx=ast.Store())]
        attrs = [n.attr for n in ast.walk(node) if is_attr_on_self(n)]
        value = ast.Tuple(elts=[ast.Str(s=attr) for attr in attrs], ctx=ast.Load())
        return [node, ast.Assign(targets=targets, value=value)]
```

Then instead of directly using `import` to load our module, we need a little extra boilerplate to shim in our `NodeTransformer`:

```
filename = 'program.py'
parsed = ast.parse(open(filename).read())
with_references = RecordReferencesTransformer().visit(parsed)
ast.fix_missing_locations(with_references)
exec compile(with_references, filename, 'exec')

print A.m.self_attributes_referenced
a = A()
a.m()
```

Output:

```
('x', 'y')
3
```

Implementing `self_methods_referenced` is left as an exercise to the reader.

Finally, the `program.py` source:

```
class A(object):
    x, y  = 1, 2
    def m(self):
        print self.x + self.y
```

Comment: That's incredible. You don't even need to **run** A() and a.m(). It's sufficient to do `print A.m.self_attributes_referenced`.

Comment: @A.JesseJiryuDavis true! I rearranged the statements to make this clear